# How to get $_GET variables from referrer url in Yii?

Tags: ajax, url, yii, upload, get

I trying upload images on server by Ajax, when server catching files the files are writing to database. But here now I need to parse referrer url to get Id.
For now I have only this solution:

```
public function actionAjaxTest()
{
  if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
  {
    echo json_encode(parse_url(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getUrlReferrer()));
  }
  Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Is Yii have any functions to encode it to variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st. Add rule to your config url rules:**

```
'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => array(
                .........
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                .........
            ),
        ),
```

**2nd. Your action will look like this:**

```
public function actionAjaxTest($id)
```

Where `$id=123` from your url '/controller/ajaxTest/123' for example.

**3rd. Where you generate url use:**

```
$this->createUrl("/controller/ajaxTest",array("id"=>$id))
```